# Making application image often locks up application

Tags: java, image, screenshot

I'm taking images of my application and often locks up the application, especially on Macs. Am I doing something wrong with it? It's surrounded by a try/catch but not throwing an error.

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    this.printAll(img.getGraphics());
    File outputfile = new File(saveImageName);
    process.props.setProperty(EnumProcess.lastSnapName.toString(), saveImageName);
    ImageIO.write(img, ext, outputfile);
```

Comment: Btw, this seems the be the offending line of code:  this.printAll(img.getGraphics());

Comment: Anything not closed/released properly?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Not that I know of. On the Mac it can lock up the first time it hits it or 3rd. On windows, it takes multiple times, 20 or so? I've not checked to see if it's related to memory use or if it happens consistently at the same iteration indicating something may be causing the failure.  Anything in particular I should look for or verify?

Comment: You should create a small, self-standing example showing this behavior and share it on Github or similar so others can actually see the problem on their computer.  My guess based on the little information so far, is that something here is not threadsafe.

Answer (score 0):

As a partial , I have 'plotting controls' on the interface frame which can be processing intensive during the repaint(). I've found that if I call the above routine at the end of void paint, it's been very stable.

A problem will arise again I'm sure when I have multiple "plotting controls" instances on the interface, each processing their own repaints.

I tried exiting out of void paint if a snapshot was in progress using flags, which caused screen glitches. So I tried, waiting for the repaint to finish before taking a snapshot (in it's own routine), but helped (lasted longer without freezing up), but wasn't a total solution.

I'll work on when repaints are called and see if I can synchronize things better. Thanks for the suggestions.